# Sqlserver 2008 : Restored Failed for Server 'System 16'(Microsoft.Sqlserver.smoextended'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error when i tried to restore the `bak` file i have

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Restore failed for Server 'SYSTEM16'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22+((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.1600. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

Can any one tell how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be in your error message. It looks like you may have taken the backup from SQL 2008 R2 and are trying to restore it to SQL 2008 R1. You can't restore backups taken on newer versions of SQL Server to older versions.